# Apache 2 virtual host configuration for subdomain redirection

Tags: apache, redirects, subdomain

I'm trying to set up a `mail` subdomain on my site that will simply redirect to my Google Apps mail account. I thought I could use the Apache 2 vhost configuration below, but it's not working:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mail.foo.com
  Redirect 301 / https://mail.google.com/a/foo.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

What else do I need to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a corresponding [A record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_record) for `mail.foo.com.` (or `*.foo.com.`) set?

Example:

```
*.foo.com. 14400 IN A 1.2.3.4
```

... or:

```
mail.foo.com. 14400 IN A 1.2.3.4
```

(Where `1.2.3.4` is the IP address of the server running Apache 2)

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, I knew there was something I'd forgotten!